# Рекурсивное копировоание файлов из директорий

Tags: cmd, bash

Добрый день!

> ls -R -1 d:/intellij_projetcs/SDN_Simulator/sdn-nfv-simulator/portal-aggregator | grep '*.war' | xargs cp -t c:/netcracker/config/sdn-sim-portal-36360/deploy

мне необходимо обойти рекурсивно все внутренние папки и скопировать из них все war файлы в папку *deploy*.
Но этот скрипт почему-то не работает. Конкретно : grep не фильтрует файлы.
PS скрипт надо запускать в среде форточки, при себе имею cygwin. Хотелось бы использовать его инструменты, но запускать строго из консоли *cmd*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'.*.war' - регулярное выражение. Вам нужно использовать grep -e (подробнее в man grep) для поиска с регулярным выражением. Либо grep '.war'.

Comment: Если использовать -e, то тогда уже grep -e ".*.war"

Comment: Да верно подмечено.

Comment: '.war$' - единственное, что сработало! Удивляет, почему регулярное выражение мое не сработало!

Comment: Вообще для этой задачи удобнее использовать find, как написал @Дож. Немного изменю его вариант:

find d:/intellij_projects/SND_Simulator/snd-nfv-simulator/portal-aggregator -name '*.war' -exec cp -t "{}"  c:/nettracker/config/sdn-sim-portal-36360/deploy/

Comment: voipp, потому что Вы неправильно написали регулярное выражение. Я показал, как оно правильно переписывается. С $ на конце ещё корректнее под задачу.

Comment: @Дож всю сознательную жизнь звездочка обозначала любые символы сколько угодно раз

Comment: чувствую, лучше бы я написал скрипт на перл

Comment: @voipp, что говорит о довольно ограниченном опыте использования регулярок в вашей сознательной жизни :) Синтаксисов regex'ов бывает очень много разных, не только PCRE.

Answer (score 1):

```
cp -t `find d:/intellij_projetcs/SDN_Simulator/sdn-nfv-simulator/portal-aggregator -name "*.war"` c:/netcracker/config/sdn-sim-portal-36360/deploy/
```

Comment: ACCESS DENIED несмотря на то, что консоль я запустил от имени администратора!

Comment: А так? touch tmp && cp -t tmp c:/netcracker/config/sdn-sim-portal-36360/deploy/

Comment: @Дож ой, а зачем изменять время изменения директории?

Comment: Это проверка того, что проблема в записи, а не чтении.